# Image is not displaying in Zoho page why?

Tags: zoho

I am trying to display Image in page which is Uploaded in the form.In the page first I fetched the  ID of the Record and based on the Record I want to display the Image
 I have used this code

```
<img src='https://creatorexport.zoho.com/DownloadFile.do?filepath=/<%=rec.FileUpload%>&sharedBy=userName&appLinkName=app1&viewLinkName=view1'>
```

//style

but It is not displaying the Image. Can anyone please let me know where I have to change so that it displays Image?

Answer (score 0):

###### To display a Image in page view

1. First, be sure that field type is File Upload not the Image field.
2. Add Formula filed and add the below expression:

   ```
   ("http://creatorexport.zoho.com/DownloadFile.do?filepath=/" + <Your Field Name> + "&sharedBy=" + zoho.adminuser) + "&appLinkName="+Zoho.Appname+&viewLinkName=<your report name>"
   ```
3. In page fetch Id of record.

   ```
   <% Variable  =  Form Name  [ID == IdFieldName];%>
   ```

   sample is

   ```
   <%r  =  Add_Event  [ID == input.EventID.toLong()];%>
   ```
4. With respect to Id get Image field

   ```
   <img src=<%=r.Formula%>>
   ```

Now Image displays in the page.